# jQuery: don't postback page with .post() method?

Tags: jquery, post, browser-history

I have a question about using jQuery's`.post()` method without posting back the containing page.

This is code for a book page in a library system. If the user clicks on the "Return book" button, I use jQuery's `.post()` to set the book returned in the database.

```
<form id="checkoutform">
<input type="submit" id="checkout" class="button" value="Return book" />
</form>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("#checkout").click(function() {  
    $.post('/transaction/', { book_id: '{{ book.id }}', user_id: username }, function(data) {
         alert(data);
         });
    });
});
```

The database transaction works find, but it also posts back the page.

This is not a problem in itself, but it alters the behaviour of the Back button - and that is a problem. If the user clicks "Return book" and then uses the Back button on the browser, they will see the book page as it was before they returned the book, so it will look as though the book is still checked out.

is there a way either to:

- avoid posting back the page with the jquery `.post()` method, and just alter the parts of the page that I need, or
- fix up the Back button so it goes straight back to the preceding page?

Thanks!

Comment: sounds like the page returns an error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, what's probably happening is that your click function is firing, and then, in addition, the default functionality (submit the form when a "submit" button is pressed) is occurring.

To prevent that, either make the button a plain button instead of a submit button, or add `return false` at the end of your click function.  Or take a look at jQuery's [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).

Comment: Absolutely right! The form was submitting, and `return false` fixes it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding `return false` to the end of a jQuery event handler will prevent the default event handler from executing.  Since in your case, the default behavior of submitting a form is to do a POST, that is what happens.

Answer (score 0):

add return false in the end of function

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("#checkout").click(function() {  
    $.post('/transaction/', { book_id: '{{ book.id }}', user_id: username }, function(data) {
         alert(data);
         });
   return false;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try throwing `return false;` in the click function. Maybe it's actually submitting the page and instead of going asynchronously. If that doesn't work, what does your ajax page look like?